# Can devices with different port settings work normally in modbus network?

Tags: modbus, rs485

We have several devices connected to Modbus network. We bought a new device that can't be tuned and has fixed settings: baudrate=19200, parity=odd, while others have baudrate=38400, parity=none. Is it possible to use them in one network, i.e. first read from old devices, and then reset serial port to read from the new device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as the devices ignore data encoded with the wrong baud rate.